# How to establish peer to peer connection between web browser

Tags: javascript, p2p

I can access my camera by the API `getusermedia()`. Is it possible to establish  browser to browser connection using `RTCpeerconnection()` API?  Which browser (PC version) will support this p2p (peer to peer) connection? I hear Chrome will support this p2p but I don't know how, if anybody has an idea please help me.

Comment: JavaScript p2p? I doubt that's possible. (However, I've been surprised by JS often enough)

Comment: Please use the shift key. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the draft of WebRTC here:

http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html

And you can read more information in: http://www.webrtc.org/

The project WebRTC, for browser based realtime communication, was open sourced by Google. So only Chorme implements it.

To enable WebRTC you should start Chrome with this switch: "--enable-media-stream".

-Mozilla has implemented the getUserMedia() API and the Aurora nightly builds contain an implementation of the Peer Connection and Data Channel APIs; preliminary support in Firefox 18.

-Opera has implemented the getUserMedia() API in its stable branch.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, you might be interested in [browserver](http://browserver.org/) which allows you to run an http server inside your browser.